# How to debug 'File in use by another process' error in Sublime Text

Tags: sftp, sublime-text-3, process-explorer

All of a sudden, today, I have started having problems uploading files with [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/3) and the [SFTP plugin](https://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp).  There have been no sytem changes, new programs installed or suchlike.  I was using it yesterday - all was fine.  I used it today - anf this problem popped up, seemingly from nowhere.

About 50% of the time I try to upload, I get the error: `failure (File in use by another process)`.

[Most people encountering this error message are having trouble saving files](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=sublime%20text%20%20file%20in%20use%20by%20another%20process&cns=0), but I have no problem with that. Just with uploading.

This is seemingly random - I might get it 5 times in a row, and then 5 times it will work ok. Then it works once, and fails twice, etc. etc. Therefore I don't think it's a consistent delay, or a case of the SFTP process 'holding on' to files for X seconds too long every time.

I have tried rebooting. I have tried un/re installing ST and the SFTP plugin. The error persists.

I then used [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) to investigate.

It is showing the `plugin_host.exe`file as holding onto the file. (My understanding is that plugin_host.exe is kind of a 'generic plugin manager' for sublime). SFTP is the only plugin I use, so that appears to confirm it's a problem with that plugin, as opposed to ST itself.

But I have no idea what step to take next in debugging this problem.

Any pointers or advice in how I might proceed would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried [contacting the plugin author](https://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp/support)?

Comment: Yeah I pinged him an email. But I figured he would be quite busy, and thought it might be worth exploring how I might debug this myself too